# Executing an external javascript once every few seconds

Tags: javascript, php, setinterval

I have a javascript code once every few seconds, I have tried the following, but it doesn't work. I know something is off. Just can't figure it out.

```
<script src="https://example.com/js/one.js"></script>
<script>
setInterval(function() {
Example.init({
    "argument1": "param1",
    "argument2": "param2",
});
},10000);)();
</script>
```

I have inserted the above code in header.php

Comment: what `)();` supposed to do? (after `setInterval(... ... 10000)`)

Comment: https://example.com/js/one.js gives me a 404

Comment: @Fiouze the domain doesn't exist. It's an example. I don't think we are allowed to post our actual urls here.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Nothing happens? Executes once? Executes in a different interval? Executes with unexpected results? Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Oh i see, I thought that was some kind of testing url for an api call. My bad. But as other mentioned there is a )() that is causing issues in the code

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the brackets at the end.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  console.log(1)
}, 1000);
```